# Protractor: More specific feedback to User?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

Say I have a page of 10 images and the 3rd and 5th don't load. How can I say something like:

2/5 images didn't load.

Or "image2.jpeg" and image5.jpeg" hasn't loaded.

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

it('should find all images', function () {
  browser.get('https://popeyes.com/');
  var imagesBrokenCount = browser.executeScript(`
  var elms = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  return [].filter.call(elms, e => e.offsetHeight > 1 && e.naturalHeight <= 1).length;
  `);
browser.sleep(1000);
expect(imagesBrokenCount).toEqual(0);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch to Protractor-specific functionality here - using [`filter()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) to filter out the broken images, then, using [`map()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) to get an array of `src` values and then using Jasmine's `fail()` to fail with a desired error message:

```
it('should find all images', function () {
  browser.get('https://www.popeyes.com');
  var brokenImages = $$("img").filter(function (img) {
    return img.getAttribute("offsetHeight").then(function (offsetHeight) {
        return img.getAttribute("naturalHeight").then(function (naturalHeight) {
            return offsetHeight > 1 && naturalHeight <= 1;
        });
    });
});
brokenImages.count().then(function (countBrokenImages) {
    if (countBrokenImages > 0) {
      console.log(countBrokenImages + " images loaded successfully");              
        brokenImages.map(function (img) {
            return img.getAttribute("src");
        }).then(function (sources) {
          fail("Failed to load the following images: " + sources.join(","));              
        })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alecxe! It is better to run in Protractor functionality. I am still getting familiar with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply return the source from the broken images and then assert that the returned array is empty:

```
browser.get('https://popeyes.com/');
var brokenImages = browser.executeScript(`
  return [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img"))
    .filter(e => e.offsetHeight > 1 && e.naturalHeight < 1)
    .map(e => e.src);
`);
browser.sleep(1000);
expect(brokenImages).toBeEmptyArray();
```